# Gridview not populating from datatable

Tags: vb.net, gridview

I'm not sure if it's because the datatable isn't filling out properly (and is therefore empty with nothing to display) or if I'm not loading it onto the gridview properly,  but here is my code:

```
    Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    'So Get all the Rows by splitting it on a NewLine Character
    Dim Rows() As String = Clipboard.GetText().Split(Environment.NewLine)

    Dim Cols() As String


    Dim DT As New DataTable


    Dim DR As DataRow
    For i As Int32 = 0 To Rows.Length - 1
        'Then For Each Row get the Columns which are tab Seperated
        Cols = Rows(i).Split(vbTab)
        DR = DT.NewRow
        'Now create a DataRow to be added to the underlying DataTable
        For j As Int32 = 0 To Cols.Length - 1
            'Now loop for each Column and Add the column data
            If DT.Columns.Count > j Then
                If (j = 2) Then

                    DR(j) = Convert.ToInt32(Cols(j))
                Else
                    DR(j) = Cols(j)
                End If
            End If
        Next
        DT.Rows.Add(DR)
    Next




    DataGridView2.DataSource = DT



End Sub
```

EDIT: When I pre-add columns to the gridview before running the program, it will populate blank data in them. When I have no columns in the gridview pre-added, nothing happens.

How do I make it so the number of columns are added dynamically by the datatable?

Comment: Is this `DT.Columns.Count` ever greater than 0 ?

Comment: Why do you think it should always be. Run the code with F11 to step through and look at the variables values as the code runs. I see nowhere that you are adding columns.

Comment: I'm not seeing where you are adding Columns into your DataTable.

Comment: Thanks, I will check that out. That's probably the issue.